# Malformed entry error while updating from terminal

Tags: updates, tor

Recently, I installed Tor browser. While installing, I did some mistake with `lsb_release` (I'm not sure about it). Now I am getting the following error when trying to update:

```
E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tor-project.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Please help me in fixing the issue.

Thanks